# Could I able to send a HTTP request using lib cURL in c/c++?

Tags: c, libcurl

I'm trying to use libcurl to send a request like below in C/C++:

```
GET https://example.com/ HTTP/1.0
Host: https://example.com
Range: bytes=0-0
Connection: keep-alive
```

PS: I tried 2 case using `:` in the end of every header's line has `"\r\n"` and the last header has `"\r\n\r\n"` (end of header signal) and not adding `"\r\n"` in the end of file with `curl_slist_append()` + `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main()
{
  CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
 
  struct curl_slist *list = NULL;
  
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/");

    list = curl_slist_append(list, "Range: bytes=0-0");
    list = curl_slist_append(list, "Connection: keep-alive");
    
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
    CURLcode ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (ret == CURLE_OK) {
      printf("success\n");
    } else {
      printf("fail\n");
    }
    curl_slist_free_all(list); /* free the list */
  }
}
```

But seems like it doesn't work.

I tried to use WireShark to capture the HTTP packages by running it with `sudo`, and filter `"http"`, but nothing is captured.

Am I right to use `curl_slist_append()` with option `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to send the headers like I want?

If that is wrong, how do I send it to an HTTP server using libcurl, or do I have to use a socket connection instead?

Comment: There's no Error return. So that make I think that I send header success.
But I can't capture anything by wireshark.. That the problem @@

Comment: I mean that the return code after curl_easy_perform()  is "CURLE_OK"

Comment: Your use of `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` is fine, but the *preferred* way to send a `Range` header is to use the [`CURLOPT_RANGE`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_RANGE.html) option instead: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RANGE, "0-0");`

Comment: You are requesting an HTTPS url, so Wireshark will not be able to display the traffic since it will be encrypted. You would need the server's private decryption key in order to view the traffic, which you won't have until you own the server.

Comment: Try to make code which shows it does not work. Your code reports it successuflly does what you want, and exists. It probably does work, then. Add more code so that it fails.